# How to install .debian.tar.gz ?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, deb

I am trying to install lobster font on my ubuntu14.04. The compressed file is of the type .debian.tar.gz.

I tried to install it using the .configure make make install method but it didn't work. Here is the terminal output :

```
~/Downloads$ tar -xzvf fonts-lobstertwo_2.0-2.debian.tar.gz

debian/
debian/control
debian/watch
debian/fonts-lobstertwo.install
debian/copyright
debian/fonts-lobster.install
debian/source/
debian/source/format
debian/repack.sh
debian/changelog
debian/compat
debian/fonts-lobstertwo.links
debian/rules

~/Downloads$ cd debian/
~/Downloads/debian$ sudo ./configure
sudo: ./configure: command not found

~/Downloads/debian$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop

~/Downloads/debian$ make install
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

Why isn't it working? Does  .**debian**.tar.gz installation work through some other process as compared to  .**deb**.tar.gz ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This file doesn't contain any font but juts the additional file one needs to make a Debian package from some other archive containing the actual fonts.

As the package `fonts-lobstertwo` is available from the official Ubuntu package sources for 14.04 you may just install that package using e.g. Software Center